# Parse NSString to NSDate in one timezone and convert it to another timezone

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Can someone help me read this string (timezone - "Pacific/Tahiti"):

```
NSString *str = @"2014-06-12 14:00:00"
```

and parse it to a NSDate in my local time zone ("Europe/London").

I know I should use `NSDateFormatter` but i can't find out how to set the initial timezone to "Pacific/Tahiti", read the string and convert it to "Europe/London".

Thanks alot!

Comment: NSDate contains no timezone.  It's the timezone of the formatter used to parse or format the date that determines the human-visible timezone.

Comment: (Presumably you need to use NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName twice to create the two timezone objects that you use to set the date formatter.)